# CentOS user management through LDAP

Tags: centos, ldap

I set up my CentOS 5.3 server to authenticate off of LDAP and am able to add users manually through Apache Directory Studio 1.4.  Now that this is setup, is there a preferred "CentOS Way" of managing users in LDAP?  There is another thread that talks about general ways to do this, but none of those solutions are available in the default CentOS package repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't an official "CentOS way" for managing users in LDAP. Which is a bit infuriating, since the default useradd/usermod/etc. tools only work with the default /etc/passwd scheme. The official LDAP server is openldap, and there are some basic command line tools available, but nothing that is out-of-the-box easy to use for user management. We use a web-based system called Gosa, another popular option is home-grown scripts built on top of the command-line LDAP tools.

Comment: Ok, this is what I feared, but I wanted to make sure.  I will check out the 3rd party tools like phpldapadmin and gosa.

Comment: +1 for Gosa .. for the curious its at https://oss.gonicus.de/labs/gosa/

Answer (score 0):

If looking up the next uid/gid is the only problem you can look at phpldapadmin. Personally I have a custom python script that does it for me...

Comment: phpldapadmin is not in the default repository.  I am looking for the "CentOS way" (which may not exist).  I'll revise the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Revised title and question.  This answer made sense before changes occurred.